# Has the definition of an adverb changed over time?

Tags: grammar, history

I was reading a modern grammar book recently and was very surprised to see that "yesterday" and "nevertheless" are regarded as adverbs.

Has the definition of an adverb been constant over the last 50 years or has it evolved?  I feel that neither yesterday nor nevertheless were defined to be adverbs in the 1970s but I could well be wrong.

Comment: Grammatical theory (or, rather, theories) is constantly developing. The idea that there is a single "right" classification of parts of speech is outdated. What else would you regard "yesterday" and "nevertheless" as? ("Yesterday" can be a noun, of course, but in "I saw him yesterday" what would you call it but an adverb?)

Comment: I prefer the treatment of what were traditionally labelled sentence adverbs/adverbials as being outside the grammar of the matrix sentence. 'Nevertheless' is then a pragmatic marker: sentence connector ... concessive and cancellative. ([Science Direct](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378216609003269))

Comment: One top-flight grammar analyses (perhaps controversially) items like "yesterday", today", "tomorrow" etc. as pronouns, one reason being that they have genitive forms "yesterday's", "today's", "tomorrow's" etc. The same grammar conventionally analyses "nevertheless" as a connective adverb, whose function is adjunct of concession.

Comment: @Colin Fine If "yesterday" can be a noun, how do you account for its inability to take determiners like other nouns do, e.g. _Yesterday / *The yesterday was my birthday_.

Comment: @BillJ: a whole class of nouns (Proper nouns) do not take determiners.

Comment: @Colin Fine Well, some proper nouns do take determiners, especially the definite article. e.g. "The Louvre", "The House of Commons", "The Ukraine", "The Colisseum", "The Times" etc. But the point is that common nouns freely take determiners, and if "yesterday" really is a noun, then it's a common noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shorter Oxford (revised Onions 1933) lists yesterday as noun and adverb.

> **Yesterday** *sb.*  Did you see my yesterday's note? *Byron.*
> All our yesterdays have lighted fools the way to dusty death. *Will Shakespeare.*
>
> *adverb*
> He was to dine, as yestesterday with the Frazers. *Jane Austen*

**Nevertheless** is only listed as an adverb. **Nonetheless** is not recorded.

However, **Notwithstanding** is given as preposition, (notwithstanding their objections...); as *adverb,* (he saw it would come to pass notwithstanding); and *conjunction,*  (Notwithstanding that it were once burned by the Duke of Burgundy. 1596);

Comment: Does this make "However" an adverb as well?

Comment: @Lembik, Yes, in 1933 (which is admittedly a generous interpretation of "fifty years ago") all four usages of "However" are labeled *adverb." .1. However I boil eggs, they end up hard, .2. & .3. However, I don't mind. .4. However did that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Many dictionaries define any word that can appear alone in an adverbial phrase to be an adverb.  'Yesterday' is a temporal noun, so it can appear adverbial (although it is really the referent of an elided '[at]').  'Nevertheless', like 'however' is an adverb, but many people are tempted to punctuate them like conjunctions (cf. 'but').  Conjunction clauses are adverbial, but they are dependent clauses.

[At] yesterday, I was hungry, but I didn't eat.

[At] yesterday, I was hungry.  Nevertheless, I didn't eat.

Comment: " 'Yesterday' is a temporal noun, so it can appear adverbial (although it is really the referent of an elided '[at]')" may well describe the historical situation, but " 'Yesterday' is an adverb because it modifies the verb, and authorities class the word in this usage as 'adverb' " is equally valid.

Comment: If "yesterday" is a noun, how do you account for its inability to take determiners like other nouns do, e.g. Yesterday / *The yesterday was my birthday.

Comment: @BillJ - 'Yesterday' is indexical - it is a type of pronoun; that's why it needs no determiner.  I merely said noun because I wanted to include other temporal nouns, like 'Monday'.

Comment: @AmI I was hoping someone would say it was a pronoun!. That's how I see it too.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - Everything in a clause, other than the subject, verbals and direct object, is adverbial.  (In memory, even the direct object is adverbial!)  I can see why some nouns are classed as adverbs, but I think it reveals a lack of understanding of what is happening.  The fewer syntax categories that a word needs, the better.

Comment: @BillJ - Yes; indexicals imply the determiner 'the' or the demonstrative 'this': he = the male, they = the group, there = the place, here = this place, then = the time, today = this day, yesterday = the day previous to this day, etc.

Comment: @AmI Pronouns are a subclass of noun, so I too usually just say NP. Your 'indexical' aligns with my 'deictic'.

Comment: @Aml BillJ's point (made as a rhetorical question) is telling. If you class 'yesterday' as a noun even when obviously acting adverbially, you are demanding a certain definition of 'the [number of] syntax categories that a word needs'. One with which many don't agree. This site contains far too many examples of certain approaches to grammar being trotted out as indisputably correct.

Comment: Words belong to categories (noun, verb, adverb etc.) as well as having functions (subject, object, adjunct etc.). In _I went to see her yesterday_, for example, the word "yesterday" carries the category label 'NP' (noun phrase) and the function label 'adjunct'. And in _yesterday was such a wonderful day_, the NP "yesterday" has the function label 'subject'. Simple basic syntax, really. It' a shame some people can't grasp it.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth (& BillJ) - "home is a wonderful place" & "I went to see her home".  'Home' is a noun (NP) that acts as subject or object.  'Yesterday' instead of 'home' would act as subject or adverbial (adjunct).  How do you know which way to parse it?  You know that 'yesterday' is adverbial because it is a temporal [pro]noun.  I could conceive of a storage method that makes 'yesterday' an adverb, but I wouldn't care to implement it.  If "he ate quickly" then 'his eating was quick'; but if "he ate yesterday", 'his eating was [at] yesterday', not 'his eating was an instance of a yesterday'.

Comment: He ate yesterday. He ate then.

Comment: 'Then' is a pronoun (the time).  I maintain that 'he ate at the time', but you think that 'then' is sometimes an adverb?

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - You should have challenged me with 'soon' or 'recently'.  These have temporal diexis but may be stored as raw adverbs rather than antecedents (if the temporal chain can still be reconstructed at decode time) - so the same might be done with 'yesterday'.  Note, however, that Google's newly released parser (Syntax-Net) gives POS=noun for the adverbial use of 'yesterday'.  Note also that yesterday, today and tomorrow contain vestigial prepositions, to which you had alluded (backwards?) with 'historical situation'.